# Automatically change Gmail signature by recipient

Tags: gmail, email-signature

Is there a way to automatically change/adjust the Gmail Signature by the Emails recipient? I'm thinking of adjustable rules or a plugin for the Gmail Webclient.

For example:

I'm preparing a mail for adam@mail.com. Normally it would add my standard signature "Best, Devan", but because I created a rule for adam@mail.com Gmail sees that the Email is addressed at adam@mail.com and automatically changes the signature that is added to the Email Footer to "Sincerely, Devan Loper".

EDIT: I already know about the Gmail Lab named "canned responses" that does something similar but it doesn't automate by recipient. That's the problem.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is out of the scope of this site but you could ask for them in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Should I flag to close this then?

Comment: No, I don't think this needs to be closed. You have a clear problem statement. That you're open to third-party tools is ancillary to the problem. The kind of questions we don't want are ones where someone has a problem, are convinced they know what sort of tool they need to solve it, and ask for help in finding the tool.

Comment: Regarding of asking for software recommendations, I think that you should remove the "chrome extension" line. By the other hand, it's granted that if anyone require more information of detailed explanation they are able to feel free to comment, so line before the last one should be removed too. For more tips about how to write questions see http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3857/88163

Comment: You might also find this useful: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: @AlE. Added your link to the FAQ referred in my previous comment :)